# How to insert regex expression as text in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Am trying to insert a regex epxression as text in mongodb but it keeps getting converted to wrong formats

```
db.getCollection('regex').insertMany([
{
    name:"collName",
    order:"29",
    regexValue:"\b({})(?i)\s\b"
}])
```

I `\b` is converted to a symbol and `\[any character]` the `\` is removed but the characters inserted as is.

escapign the slash worked, but this will require lot of rework, anyway to do that some other way ?

Comment: This is how JS works. You can try python which has raw strings.